Llamar a api facebook para obtener el page-id
Estoy intentando traer los datos del usuario para obtener el page-id y poder enviar mensajes a través de la Api de Facebook Messenger.  Me lanzá el siguiente error:
Data: {"error":{"message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API
call.","type":"OAuthException","code":3,"fbtrace_id":"AEl0A7GSvbK01y2DyH9dZPh"}}

end point:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/user_id/accounts?access_token=access_token

tengo los permisos configurados en la app:
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_read_engagement
pages_show_list


En el valor de access_token debes usar tu user access token! y define tu user_Id

sí los tengo, no hay problema con eso, no lo quise poner

El problema sin duda se debe a permisos, aunque veo, ya que tienes definidos los permisos:

pages_manage_metadata
pages_show_list permissions.

Es importante revises que con la cuenta que tratas de realizar la llamada sea administrador o qué se encuentre registrada como usuario de prueba

y es importante que en el endpoint que indicas definas el valor de tu user_id y tu user access token:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/*user_id*/accounts?access_token=*user_access_token*


ok lo intentaré, daré aviso al administrador para que me agregue.  EL access token los estoy obteniendo con https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=app-id&client_secret=my-secret-key&grant_type=client_credentials

Estoy como usuario tester, ahora muestra esto, estoy usando mi user_id de facebook: "message": "(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.

Me parece que necesitas el permiso "pages_read_engagement" y definir tu correcto user_id de Facebook
